# Is "Halaal" an invalid spelling of "halal"?

Tags: orthography, loanwords

In [Someone Trolled Pauline Hanson By Sending Her A Jar of Halal-Certified Vegemite](http://junkee.com/someone-trolled-pauline-hanson-sending-jar-halal-certified-vegemite/92657), "halaal" is described as an invalid spelling of "halal":

> An enterprising Australian has sent a jar of Vegemite to Pauline Hanson, using Kmart’s custom name generator to slap the word “Halaal (sic)” on the label.
>
> ...
>
> But why does the jar spell halal wrong? Turns out Vegemite doesn’t allow people to print “halal” on the jars, but “halaal” is fine.

Is spelling it with two consecutive "a"s considered incorrect, or just a variant spelling?

Comment: There are various transliteration systems for converting Arabic into English, and *halal*, *hallal* and *halaal* are all possible.

Comment: The English more commonly used spelling is "halal": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=halal%2Chalaal%2C+hallal&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Chalal%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhalal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHalal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHALAL%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chalaal%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhalaal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHalaal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Challal%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BHallal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhallal%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Considering that I cannot make an absolute statement here, hence, in case you need a reference, then you can look at an article written by a Pakistani: <a href = "https://en.dailypakistan.com.pk/viral/spit-it-out-now-trident-gum-contain-pork-declared-haraam/>Trident: Halal or Haram</a>. <br /> Even in that article, just as @JOSH has commented, the author uses both “haram” and “haraam” to spell “haram”. In Pakistan, where I reside, authors and public commonly use “halal”. However, I cannot comment on its correctness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't speak Arabic, but I can read the language (as a Muslim), and it's not a question that can be answered with "yes" or "no". Arabic script is entirely different from Latin, and letters are completely unrecognisable. Even *Allah*, which is the only spelling I have ever seen of *God* in Arabic, is not technically correct. "الله" would be correct. I'm sure **halaal** would be just as recognisable as **halal** in context, but there's really no difference. It's a variant, and many words are similarly varied:

**Ramadhan** is the ninth month in the Islamic calendar.
**Ramadan** is also the month in which Muslims fast.

It's like someone spewing gibberish at you and then asking you to write it down. **Halal** (or **Halal**) are simply how the majority of the people who use the Latin alphabet have chosen to represent the word.

Side note: not sure if "fast" is used correctly then.

Comment: "Fast" is spelt correctly. The word "breakfast" is derived from "break" and "fast", by the way.

Comment: This is a fine answer!

Comment: I wasn't worried about my spelling of the word "fast", just if it was correctly used as a verb. That's a fact that people remind me every year during Ramadan!